# Getting the last letter of two strings in prolog

Tags: string, prolog

I am trying to get the last letter of two strings in prolog and output them in prolog. example: "body", "hello" OUTPUT should be X = yo.

I have this method so far

```
lastletter(S, X) :-
     name(S, N),
     reverse(N, [F|_]),
     name(X, [F]).

twoterms(S, N, X) :-
name(S, A),
reverse(A, [F|_]),
name(Q, [F]),
name(N, Z),
reverse(Z, [E|_]),
name(Y,[E]),
atom_concat(X,Y,Q).
```

My lastletter methods works out. I am having difficulty coming up with a solution to twoterms. thanks

Comment: the last atom_concat/3 call should be written as atom_concat(Q,Y,X).

Comment: In ISO Prolog, just say `sub_atom(S,_,1,0,X).`